# Unable to append new rows to a saved dataframe by running Python code

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, deep-learning

### Problem

Code block to append new rows to an existing data frame in a directory and saving it back to the same directory.

---

### Example

If I run this code 4 times I want 4 new rows in the data frame to be saved

```
path = 'C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/'  
data_log = path + "data_log/"
categories = ['Black','White']
crop_size = (75,75)
epochs = 20
Dense_layer = 1
Dense_neuron =512
sampling='oversampling'
if os.path.isdir(data_log) is False:
    os.makedirs(data_log)
if os.path.isdir(f'{data_log}test_models.csv') is False:
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Dense_layers':[],
                  'Dense_neurons':[],
                  'Epochs':[],
                  'Sampling':[]
                  })
df.to_csv(f'{data_log}test_models.csv')
df = pd.read_csv(f'{data_log}test_models.csv',index_col=0)
df1 = {'Dense_layers':Dense_layer,
                  'Dense_neurons':Dense_neuron,
                  'Epochs':epochs,
                  'Sampling':sampling
                  }
with open(f'{data_log}test_models.csv', 'a') as f:
    df.append(df1,ignore_index = True).to_csv(f, header=False)
```

---

### Current Output

This is what the output looks like

```
df  
Out[38]:   
Empty DataFrame  
Columns: [Dense_layers, Dense_neurons, Epochs, Sampling]. 
Index: []
```

---

### Expected Output

This is what I want the output to look like if I ran this code block 4 times

```
   Dense_layers  Dense_neurons  Epochs      Sampling
0             1            512      20  oversampling
1             1            512      20  oversampling
2             1            512      20  oversampling
3             1            512      20  oversampling
```

Comment: append returns dataframe. so you would need to assign it again, it does not append to the same dataframe. try `df=df.append(df1,ignore_index = True) df.to_csv(f, header=False)`

Comment: @simpleApp Thank you for your response. I did try it and so when I ran the code once it stored one row of the values and on running it again, it doesn't store additional rows. I'm trying to create a dataframe in which I can store multiple hyperparameter values for each run. So that I can look at it later for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

there were some fixes needed:

1. `os.path.isdir(f'{data_log}test_models.csv')` need to check the file not the directory.
2. open file in append mode is not needed as the data frame is already concatenated. in pandas there is way like df.to_csv("myfile.csv",mode='a')
   the complete code is as(pls look for the comment, as I tried to fix your code instead of rewriting it.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path # change 1: import Path
path = '/Users/xxxxx/Downloads'  
data_log = path + "/data_log/" # file path need separator or can use os.path.join or change it for windows
fpath=f'{data_log}test_models.csv' # change 2, so file is saved in a variable
categories = ['Black','White']
crop_size = (75,75)
epochs = 20
Dense_layer = 1
Dense_neuron =512
sampling='oversampling'
if os.path.isdir(data_log) is False:
    os.makedirs(data_log)
#if os.path.isdir(f'{data_log}test_models.csv') is False: # this time need to check the existence of the file
if Path(f'{data_log}test_models.csv').exists() is False: # change 2
    print("file need to be created")
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Dense_layers':[],
                  'Dense_neurons':[],
                  'Epochs':[],
                  'Sampling':[]
                  })
    df.to_csv(f'{data_log}test_models.csv') # change 3, indent with IF

df = pd.read_csv(f'{data_log}test_models.csv',index_col=0)
df1 = {'Dense_layers':Dense_layer,
                  'Dense_neurons':Dense_neuron,
                  'Epochs':epochs,
                  'Sampling':sampling
                  }
#with open(f'{data_log}test_models.csv', 'a') as f: # not needed, as dataframe is appended, "a" mode will duplicate the rows
df=df.append(df1,ignore_index = True)
df.to_csv(fpath)
```